# React native button position

Tags: button, react-native

I have a problem with a button position on react native.

For me the code is ok but this horrible button doesn't move?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Alert, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';


export default class App extends Component {
  _onPressButton() {
    Alert.alert('You are Famous ! ')
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button style={styles.buttonContainer}
        title="Press me"
        onPress={this._onPressButton}
      />
    </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1'
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 20,
    left: 40
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried wrapping the button into a view, it works.

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Button
          title="Press me"
          onPress={this._onPressButton}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

The button is a component, that is made using a Touchable, it doesn't use the styles passed as props. You can have a look at the [Button source code here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/Button.js).

Answer (score 0):

Just put your styling inside a `View` Component like this instead of inside your `Button`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Alert, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';


export default class App extends Component {
  _onPressButton() {
    Alert.alert('You are Famous ! ')
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
      <Button
          title="Press me"
          onPress={this._onPressButton}
      />
    </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 20,
    left: 40
  }
});
```